# How to capture Click event of button when its overlapped with Bitmap object

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am trying to capture click even on button when the button and a bitmap objects are overlapped but unable to do so.

Here is how my object looks like [image: button and bitmap overlapped]

The green and red portion are part of bitmap image and the blue (Add) is button

both have similar properties like `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` hence they overlap and this is my requirement as well

I am using usual setOnClickListener against button

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
add.setOnClickListener(this);
```

similarly I use `setOnClickListener` for my bitmap as well

The white color behind the button is actually the TRANSPARENT color used for bitmap

Could somebody help me to get the click event captured for button or is there any other way I can take to get this done (please note: I can't remove bitmap)

Comment: Since code used is too big, I didn't post everything, which part of the code you want to look at it?

Comment: How are you distinguishing between button and bitmap object? What happens when you click on button and bitmap? I guess clicking on button would also select the bitmap's click listener.

Comment: Yeah this is my problem, I am not able to distinguish. Always the bitmap's click listener is called. Button's never getting called.

Comment: I'll suggest you to wrap a button by any layout tag. <LinearLayout><Button/></LinearLayout> may this work.

Comment: Add is visible only because the color of the bitmap used is transparent otherwise it would not have even visible.. Is there a way where I can find if there is an object at the place where user is clicked or touched?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71427/discussion-between-abdulh-and-apurva).

Comment: Sorry I cannot join you in chat. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order in your xml layout. Put Button after ImageView. Can you post your xml please?

Comment: Thanks @Admir that solved the issue... just moved button above the bitmap it worked.. Thanks a lot